# Ангуляр не видит линк на запрос с БД

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

У меня есть БД. Я написала запросы в WebAPI к  этой БД.
Линк с этими запросами когда я запускаю проект WebAPI работает коректно.
Но  я передаю этот линк  в Ангуляр в TheatreService.ts и получаю ошибку и не  отображается у меня то что мне нужно

theatre.service.ts

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Theatre } from './theatres.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TheatresService {
  theatreUrl = 'http://localhost:54313/api/Theatre';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
   /** Get teatres from the server */
   getTheatres() {
     return this._http.get<Theatre[]>(this.theatreUrl);
   }
}
```

Component.ts

```
 import { TheatresService } from './../../shared/theatres/theatres.service';
import { Theatre } from '../../shared/theatres/theatres.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   theatres$: Theatre[];

  constructor(private theatreService: TheatresService)
   {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    return this. getTheatres();
  }

  getTheatres(): void {
    this.theatreService.getTheatres()
      .subscribe(theatres => this.theatres = theatres);
  }
}
```

Component.html

```
<div class="p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white">
  <ul class="theatres">
    <li *ngFor='let theatre of theatre'>
      <a routerLink="/detail/{{theatre.id}}">
        {{theatre.name}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

И я  не пойму что нетак. уже много видео пересмотрела на ютубе. игру  на оф сайте ангуляра -hero сделал(но там они локальный БД используют)

Может вы увидете ошибку?

Какую ошибку выдает

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at TheatresService.getTheatres (theatres.service.ts:16)
    at App.Component.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:18)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:27788)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:38472)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:38411)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:39433)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:39376)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:3)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39364)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38376)
```

UPD:
theatre.service.ts

```
 import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Theatre } from './theatres.model';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import {MessageService} from './message.service';


@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TheatresService {
  private theatreUrl = 'api/theatres';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-type': 'application.json' })
  };
   constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService: MessageService) {}
   /** Get teatres from the server */
   getTheatres(): Observable<Theatre[]> {
     return this.http.get<Theatre[]>(this.theatreUrl)

     .pipe(
       tap(_=>this.log('fetched theatre')),
       catchError(this.handlError<Theatre[]>('getTheatre', []))
     );
   }

     /** GET theatre by id. Return `undefined` when id not found */
  getTheatreNo404<Data>(id: number): Observable<Theatre> {
    const url = `${this.theatreUrl}/?id=${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Theatre[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        map(theatre => theatre[0]), // returns a {0|1} element array
        tap(h => {
          const outcome = h ? `fetched` : `did not find`;
          this.log(`${outcome} theatre id=${id}`);
        }),
        catchError(this.handlError<Theatre>(`getHero id=${id}`))
      );
  }

  getTheatre(id: number): Observable<Theatre> {
    const url = `${this.theatreUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Theatre>(url).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`fetched theatre id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handlError<Theatre>(`getTheatre id=${id}`))
    );
  }

  private handlError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }

  /** Log a TheatreService message with the MessageService */
  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`TheatresService: ${message}`);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
   import { InMemoryDataServiceTheatre } from './shared/theatres/in-memory-data.service';
import { TheatresService } from './shared/theatres/theatres.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LeftRegionComponent } from './components/left-region/left-region.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LeftRegionComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataServiceTheatre, {dataEncapsulation: false}
    ),
  ],
  providers: [TheatresService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

in-memory-data-service.ts

```
 import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Theatre } from './theatres.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InMemoryDataServiceTheatre implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const theatres = [
      { id: 11, name: 'театр' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Опера'},
      { id: 13, name: 'Оперета' },
    ];
    return {theatres};
  }
}
```

left-region.component.ts

```
 import { TheatresService } from './../../shared/theatres/theatres.service';
import { Theatre } from '../../shared/theatres/theatres.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'left-region',
  templateUrl: './left-region.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./left-region.component.css']
})
export class LeftRegionComponent implements OnInit {
   theatres: Theatre[];

  constructor(private theatreService: TheatresService)
   {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTheatres();
  }

  getTheatres(): void {
    this.theatreService.getTheatres()
      .subscribe(theatres => this.theatres = theatres);
  }
}
```

theater.model.ts

```
 export class Theatre {
  id : number;
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96844/discussion-on-question-by-olena-novitska--------).

Comment: сделайте компонент, примеров полно, вы же упорно пытаетесь скрестить разные способы